# How to redirect user to external site's response via ActioResult in ASP .Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

Well the title must be very confusing and I'm not sure I wrote it right. Here's my situation. I have controller with some action. What I want to do is to post some data to external site using `WebClient` and redirect user to external site's response on this post. What I have so far is the following: I get response like byte array and convert it to `FileContentResult`. But I'm really not sure that this is correct, since I want user to be on external site after post was made, do some stuff there, and then he will be redirected back to my site. I'm implementing payment system and I'm sure there are some casual and more correct ways of implementation but not like the following:

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "arg1", "val1" },
        { "arg2", "val2" }
    };
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {    
       byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://external-site.com/some-service",data);
       return new FileContentResult(response, "text/html");
   }
}
```

Also as an option I could (and I did it before) create partial view widget with from which will post data to external site and all necessary data written to hidden inputs like below:

```
public PartialViewResult Action()
{
   var model = new Model {Arg1 = "val1", Arg2 = "val2", Url = "http://external-site.com/some-service"};
   return PartialView(model);
}

<form action='@Model.Url' method="POST">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Arg1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Arg2)
    <input type="submit" value="Pay with blah-blah">
</form>
```

In this case `Arg1` and `Arg2` are basically invoice amount, currency etc. But in my case there some values I don't want to be sent to user in rendered html so I want to make this post in controller via `WebClient` but I'm not sure how to handle external response correctly and redirect user, according to this response.

Comment: Should the call come to your controller to do the post?, i suggest you can use Jquery crossdomain Ajax - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (if you are using jquery already). By this you don't need to worry about sending response back...

Comment: @SridharVenkat, I want the call to be MADE from controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too sure I'm following but I don't understand the need to make the post request from your controller action method with 'WebClient'. Isn't it neater to make the post request from your view directly?

I'd suggest placing a form in your view that post this data to the external site directly

Hope it makes sense

### Edit based on comment

@Dmytro, you don't need to send the contents of the response to the user. That's wrong and you will end up sending sensitive info to the user. What you need to do is send the required XML in a POST request, parse the response which is an xml as well and then redirect the user to the url provided in the `NavigateUrl` element.

By the way, I'm dropping a minimalistic code sample here...

```
try
{
    byte[] formContentBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your xml request content");

    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://merchantapi.apac.paywithpoli.com/MerchantAPIService.svc/Xml/transaction/initiate"));
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.ContentLength = formContentBytes.Length;

            var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(formContentBytes, 0, formContentBytes.Length);


            var response = request.GetResponse();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YOUR_XML_SERIALIZABLE_DATACONTRACT));
            YOUR_XML_SERIALIZABLE_DATACONTRACT responseData = serializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());

            reqStream.Close();
            response.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

Notice that the `YOUR_XML_SERIALIZABLE_DATACONTRACT` is just an xml seriablizable object that you have to define using `XmlRoot`, etc.

Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: Well I actually just edited my post. There are some values I don't want to be visible to user. Even if they are in hidden fields they still are accessible and can be read.

Comment: Dmytro, I don't think you will be able to do what you are planning. Even if you send the response to the user, it's very likely that your user won't be able to do anything from then on because most of these payment gateways will validate anything that's posted their servers against forgery attacks.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand why you can't place this data inside the form. I mean, how sensitive is it that the user can't see it? What can they do with this information?

Comment: Payment system requires merchant code and authentication code to be posted with invoice details (currency, amount, success/fail urls etc) to login merchant to their system. I dont want these merchant and authentication codes to be visible for user.

Comment: That sounds extremely vulnerable and unsecured. If the invoice processing was only a matter of posting the data and wait for a response back from the payment gateway it'll be just fine,  requiring the end users to carry extra processing is ridiculous.  There doesn't seem to be a safe way to do this. What payment system is it?

Comment: It's [POLi payments](http://www.polipayments.com). As you can see [here](http://www.polipaymentdeveloper.com/doku.php?id=initiateexample) they send invoice details such as `CurrencyAmount` etc and login details - `AuthenticationCode` and `MerchantCode` in the same request o0.

Comment: I added an sample code as well so you get any idea of how to go forward

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense for me. I probably learned documentation badly. **The URL returned by the InitiateTransaction web service is the URL that a merchant should redirect the customer to, in order to continue with their POLi™ payment**. I think I can handle this. ))) Thank a lot for the tip.